# Make a HDD partition work like USB bootable in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

How can I make HDD partition work like a iso bootable for a Windows iso?

What I have:

-Ubuntu 16.04 (dev/sda)

-Partition of NTFS (16GB) (dev/sdb3)

-Partition of NTFS (100GB) (dev/sdb2)

-Windows ISO

What I already do:

1) I already have  a NTFS partition with 16GB  (dev/sdb3)

2) I already extract the files of Windows ISO In the partition (dev/sdb3)

3) I already set the flag "booteable" to the partition (dev/sdb3)

Goal: I want to keep Ubuntu on /dev/sda and install Windows on dev/sdb2, with the partition dev/sdb3 (working like a usb bootable)

Comment: You can't make a HDD partition behave like a pendrive. A pendrive is such a useful thing that you shouldn't avoid investing that small amount of money.

Comment: For the moment is right i can't make a HDD partition behave like a (boot) pendrive, that is the reason why i am asking how to do properly. But is possible to make HDD partition work like a booteable pendrive (just the functionality of boot an iso make it installable). It works with ubuntu iso... but i don't prepare correct the windows iso from ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want a persistent live Ubuntu on sda3? You can place a Ubuntu ISO on sdb3 and use grub on sda1 to loop mount it. You can use either a casper-rw file, (max 4GB), or casper-rw partition for persistence if required. Let me know if you want instructions. It is also possible to clone a USB install to hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

### Boot ISO from Grub

Place the Ubuntu ISO at the root of the sda3.

Modify /boot/grub/grub.cfg on sda1 as shown:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Ubuntu-18.04 64-bit ISO" {
    set root=(hd0,3)
    set isofile="/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile splash --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

**If you want persistence:**

Add the word "persistent" to the menuentry:

```
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile splash persistent --
```

Either create an ext4 partition labeled casper-rw.

Or create a casper-rw file and place it next to the ISO:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512
sudo mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F casper-rw
```

(where count=512 is persistence size, with max 4GB).

Comment: It's what the OP wants, so...  **+1  0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Using a ISO file almost feels like cheating but I believe that ISO's loopmount as fast as a squashfile extracts.